# Plot barplot for all non zero columns only

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a `data.frame` with a single record and a N numeric columns. 
I would like to graph in `R` as a barplot of all columns having non-zero value  on the same graph in `ggplot`.

For example:

```r
df <- data.frame(a=1, b=0, c=10, d=20)
```

I transposed the `data.frame` but didn't manage to name both columns.

Note: Python implements the same graph though `sns`:

```
sns.barplot(x = 'Name', y = 'count', data*)
```

Comment: Please don't post pictures of data, they are nearly impossible to use. Share data as copy/pasteable text, e.g., `dput(your_data[1:10, 1:5])` for the first 10 rows and first 5 columns---plenty of data to demonstrate solutions on.

Comment: Also, in R, `NA` is used for missing data, `0` means literally zero, and `NULL` is for objects that are undefined (different than missing values). When you had a picture of your data up, there were no `NA` or `NULL` values, but there were some `0`s. Please be very specific by what you mean when you say "columns having non null value".

Comment: All columns are numeric . Question updated. Thanks

Comment: **Please share data** as *copy/pasteable text*, e.g., **`dput(your_data[1, 1:5])`** for the first (only) row and first 5 columns. Type that command into R, replacing `your_data` with the actual name of your data frame, and edit the result into your question.

Comment: Please also note the difference between a **bar plot** (discrete/categorical x-axis, 1 bar per category, each bar shows a count or value) vs a **histogram** (continuous x-axis, binned into bars covering intervals, total area of bars adds up to 1). Your python code produces a bar plot, is that what you want? Or do you want a histogram?

Comment: I am using Discrete  data so the barplot  is more convenient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In base R this is as easy as

```
barplot(unlist(df[1, df[1, ] != 0]))
```

[image]

If you prefer `ggplot2` graphics,

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  gather(key, value) %>%
  filter(value != 0) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = key, y = value)) +
  geom_col()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

For doing bar plot, you can use `tidyr` to pivot your data into a longer format compatible with ggplot and `filter` to remove zero values:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
df=data.frame(a=1, b=0, c=10, d=20)
df %>% pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Values") %>% filter(., Values != 0)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Variable Values
  <chr>     <dbl>
1 a             1
2 c            10
3 d            20
```

And if you are combining it with `ggplot`, it gives you:

```r
df %>% pivot_longer(everything(), names_to = "Variable", values_to = "Values") %>% filter(., Values != 0) %>%
  ggplot(., aes(x = Variable, y = Values, fill= Variable))+
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

[image]

Comment: OK. got it . 

That's great,  Can you  deploy the same though **dplyr** library .

Comment: Sorry, I forget about the `filtering` of zero values, I'm editing my answer